# Error using letsencrypt with Shiny Server Pro

Tags: r, shiny-server

I am trying to configure Shiny Server Pro with a SSL certificate from Letsencrypt. I follow these commands to create my certificate as described here: https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-other

```
sudo apt-get install letsencrypt
sudo systemctl stop shiny-server
letsencrypt certonly --standalone -d pbisny.org -d www.pbisny.org
```

I add this line to `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`

```
 ssl /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbisny.org/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbisny.org/cert.pem
```

And start the server.

```
sudo systemctl start shiny-server
```

I then get this error:

```
Job for shiny-server.service failed because a configured resource limit
was exceeded. See "systemctl status shiny-server.service" and
"journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here are the details of `systemctl status shiny-server.service`

```
shiny-server.service - ShinyServer
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sat 2016-10-22 12:29:19 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 18702 ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 5 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18685 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18684 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid >> /var/l
 Main PID: 18684 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 22 12:29:11 pbis-pro systemd[1]: Starting ShinyServer...
Oct 22 12:29:14 pbis-pro systemd[1]: shiny-server.service: PID file /var/run/shiny-server.pid not readable (yet?) after 
Oct 22 12:29:19 pbis-pro systemd[1]: Failed to start ShinyServer.
Oct 22 12:29:19 pbis-pro systemd[1]: shiny-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 22 12:29:19 pbis-pro systemd[1]: shiny-server.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

I will admit, I am not a sys admin. Any help figuring out what this error means is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have Pro you're likely to get fast support from RStudio support channels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The following commands create the certificate:

```
sudo apt-get install letsencrypt
letsencrypt certonly --standalone -d domain.com -d www.domain.com
```

Here is the server section of my `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    redirect "https://domain.com" 302 true;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443;
  ssl /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Only up tp 20 connections per Shiny process and at most 3 Shiny processes
    # per application. Proactively spawn a new process when our processes reach 
    # 90% capacity.
    utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
```

}

Last, restart the shiny server.

```
sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had such an issue, it usually occurs when a curly bracket at the end or a semi colon is missed out in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

This error message:

> Job for shiny-server.service failed because a configured resource
> limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status shiny-server.service" and
> "journalctl -xe" for details.

appears when there is an error with the conf file `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`.

To check the details of the error that triggered this message, check the logs in `/var/log/shiny-server.log`. One line should have someting with `Error loading config:` followed by the details that will help you fix your config file.